# Reading a line from a file without advancing the line counter with Perl

Tags: perl

I want to be able to read the "next line" without increasing the line counter, so that the next time a read command is isued it will read the same line.

example:

*this is the first line*
*this is the second line*
*this is the third line*

I want to be able to know that the second line says "this is the second line" but not advancing my counter so that my program:

```
print <>;
print unknown_read_command;
print <>;
```

will print on the screen:

this is the first line
this is the second line
this is the second line

And in a more general, how can I change and move the pointer to the line in any direction and any amount that I want?

Comment: You want to "peek" rather than read the next line. http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=181068 (I don't actually know perl, but that's the term). According to that link it might not be easy or elegant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fetch the file position for a filehandle with [tell](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tell.html), and set it with [seek](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html):

```
my $pos = tell $fh;
# ...
seek $fh, $pos, 0 or die "Couldn't seek to $pos: $!\n";
```

Comment: Not all sources of input are seekable though.

Answer (score 3):

If you're reading line by line, another way to do this is with [`Tie::File`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;

my $fn = "foo.bar";

tie my @myFileLines, 'Tie::File', $fn or die "$?";

print STDOUT $myFileLines[0];
print STDOUT $myFileLines[1];
print STDOUT $myFileLines[1]; # print second line twice

untie @myFileLines;
```

Using file seek methods is more generic and you'll have to search for newline delimiters yourself, which Windows complicates with a proprietary newline.